# INSERT INTO 'table' that stored in a variable

Tags: mysql

How can i use my variable, which stores database table name in mysql query.
Example:

```
$myTable = "customers";
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO $myTable (smthg) VALUES ("value")");
```

I'm very new for mysql so sorry if this question is pretty stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO $myTable (smthg) VALUES ('$mytable')");
```